# How to use Wait.Until with Selenium C# for existing element

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I looking for a way to use the `wait.until` in selenium(C#) , but for existing element. That way:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "SomeID")]
public IWebElement SearchButton { get; set; }
```

now ,  I would like to use the wait.until for the element above.
any way I can do that?
Thanks
Yaniv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an abstract page object as parent to your page object and call an abstract method, which is implemented in the children pages, from the constructor:

```
public abstract class AbstractPage
{
    protected AbstractPage()
    {
        WaitUntilExist();
    }

    protected abstract void WaitUntilExist();
}

public class MyPage : AbstractPage
{
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "SomeID")]
    private IWebElement SearchButton;

    public MyPage()
    {
    }

    protected override void WaitUntilExist()
    {
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("SomeID")));
    }
}
```

The method `WaitUntilExist()` will be called from the parent constructor before the elements initialization in the child page. Since it's abstract the method in the child class will be excuted.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the quick response. 
that's a good solution, but what if my project\solution contains about 30 classes of PageObjects? each one of them will have a unique AbstractPage? Or, I can actually just call the abstract page from each page object and override it?

do you suggest using this instead?
 var wait = new WebDriverWait(_webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
            IWebElement element = wait.Until(driver=>);

Comment: @YanivEliav  No, they will all inherit from a single AbstractPage. Since the implementation of `WaitUntilExist()` is in the child class you can wait there for elements unique to this page or not at all (just leave the method empty).

Comment: @YanivEliav If you call `AbstractPage` from each child as an object (he wont be abstract by the way) you will be able to do this only **after** `SearchButton` was initialized, so there is no point waiting anymore.