# Selenium doesn't click on element that is not displayed on a current screen

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I open a page and ask selenium to click on a button that is placed at the bottom of this page. The button is not displayed on the current screen (so you have to scroll down to see it). As I know *selenium have to scroll to an element automatically when I use `Click()` method.*

**Unfortunately when I perform `Click()` method it only scrolls to the element without clicking on it.**

**When** I make a breakpoint before clicking on the element **and** scroll to it manually **then** it clicks on the element well.

**I have Selenium Webdriver C# v. 2.48.2**

**I use ChromeDriver v. 47.0.2526.106 m**

It seems to me that this problem has been present in the previous versions (so, for a long time) but some versions ago I could use "Scroll to element" method that solved this problem. **Now the method I used doesn't work.**

**The method was the following:**

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", webElement);
```

Comment: I guess there is some async work going on, maby wait for window.onload?

Comment: try to focus on it first before clicking

Comment: Any exception do you get?

Comment: @Saifur I didn't get any exception after clicking on the element, the code just continue executing.

OlegMeleshko how to do it? If you are talking about scrolling to the element I don't know how to do it as the last version of WebDriver changed something and I can't use my old code to do it.

RolandStarke I'm so sorry but I can't understand what you are talking about. I don't use any async code in my tests.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Actions` to scroll

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(elementToClick).Build().Perform();
elementToClick.Click();
```

Comment: I tried, thanks. It displayed me the next error on the second string: Object does not match target type. I tried the same code before but without "Build" method. It displayed the same error.

Comment: @DenisKoreyba  maybe you can try to move to the element parent.

Comment: By the way, make sure the element was really initialized and not null.

Comment: The element is initialized correctly and is not null. I tried to scroll to another element and it worked well. But it's not a really good solution for me. Now I have to understand what is wrong with scrolling to the first element. The difference now is in their initialization. The first one (that doesn't work) initialize by PageFactory and the second one (that works) just by "FindElement" method.

Comment: @DenisKoreyba The page factory sometimes initialize elements too soon, so that even if they are not null you still can't interact with them. Look at my answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702454/how-to-use-wait-until-with-selenium-c-sharp-for-existing-element/34702765?noredirect=1#comment57151873_34702765), this is how I deal with this problem.